# Detecting when a windows store app crashes

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

Is there any smart way to detect when an application has crashed? I want to use this information to be able to send a crash report to our servers.

The only thing I've found is checking:

```
LaunchActivatedEventArgs args.PreviousExecutionState == 
      ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated
```

When the application is started next time, however can I be sure that the applicatoin crashed just because it has "Terminated" execution state?
How else can I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) or [Application.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception) events.